# Will there be water pressure/flow into the pipe with this setting?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture, water-tank

I have a space in balcony of my 1st floor house where I intend to keep a tank around the height same as that of the water pipe which leads to my bathroom taps. Will there be problems related to  flow/pressure into the bathroom tap.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Gravity Tank in question.

Comment: Is this a pressure tank?

Answer (score 1):

Pressure at the tap -- if pressure isn't being supplied by a pump, which I assume it isn't in this case -- depends on the height of the column of water. The rain barrels in my back yard are elevated 4 feet above ground level to increase the available pressure, and it's still much, much less than what I get out of the municipal water supply. I can run drip irrigation from it, or fill a watering can;  I could not run a sprinkler without adding a pump to the system.

When doing this sort of thing, also remember that water is *heavy*. My two rain barrels approach 2000 pounds.   Unless your proposed tank is small, make *very* sure that whatever is supporting it can handle that additional weight, or you may do serious damage to the building... And remember to allow for lever-arm effects as well as direct weight.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure tanks are intended to overcome one- and two-story elevation rises. You should have no problems.

Comment: clarification needed-the bathroom taps are on the same height level as the tank, will it be good ?There is no top-bottom flow of water from tank,its parellel.

Comment: Well, if a pressure tank can accommodate a two-story rise, logic would indicate that it can also handle zero rise. I don't understand the confusion.

Comment: Well,please correct me if I am incorrect, pressure tank and gravity tanks are two different things right? I am dealing with normal gravity tank. Hope this does not change the equation

Comment: Oh, well that's different. I suggest that you edit your post to be more clear, and obviously my answer wasn't correct.

Comment: isherwood, Thank you for your time. I guess it's this logic that the gravity tank's pressure is directly proportional to the height might work against my setup. The pipe from the lower part of the tank will be leading to the taps (perpendicular tap on the line) . I guess I would have to think of something else?